# I am getting "407 Proxy Authorization Required" error when I try to login to Data Loader

Tags: data-loader

I get "407 Proxy Authorization Required" error when I try to login from Salesforce Data Loader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is outlined in [Configure Data Loader](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=configuring_the_data_loader.htm&type=0). You need to go to Settings, and then configure the username and password for your proxy (typically your network login).